# LOOKUP and MATCH query

Tags: excel

Basically I have a table which lists products A-H in column A and then in the next ten columns are features of each product. So each product is listed and then I tick a box to say whether or not it has that feature.

What I want to be able to do is to write in one cell a product, say product `b`, and then in the cell next to it have return another product that has at least four matching features.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How do you know which product should be returned from all the available products?

Comment: thats the whole purpose

Comment: I don't see the logic in that purpose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNTESTED

I take it that unticked boxes for the same feature on two products does not count as a match. Presumably more than two products may have more the same four or more features that match so different answers may be equally valid (I guess @Jerry's point). Hopefully the following describes a way to achieve both a single product in the cell next to your “Write cell” (here M1) while also indicating all qualifying possibilities.

Copy A2:A9 to A12
In B12, copied across and down to K19:

```
=IF(MATCH($M$1,$A$1:$A$10,0)=ROW()-10,"",1*AND((INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+64)&MATCH($M$1,$A$1:$A$10,0))=B2),B2<>""))
```

In N1: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A12:A19,MATCH("CF",M12:M19,0)),"")`

In M12 and copied down to M19: `=IF(SUM(B12:K12)>3,"CF","")`

Comment: This is so close to being right! It puts a "1" in the coloum of each feature if it matches it if its right but it doesn't display what products have four or more matches? Unless I missed a step.